# ¿Cómo unir dos diccionarios en Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, diccionarios

Estoy usando Python y quiero unir estos dos diccionarios:

```
dic1 = {1:"hola", 2:"adios", 3:"hasta luego"}
dic2 = {4:"¿Cómo estás?", 5:"¿Te encuentras bien?"}
```

¿Cómo puedo hacerlo?

Por ahora había intentado esto, uniendolo todo en `dic3`, pero me parece que hago muchas transformaciones y es poco elegante:

```
dic1 = {1:"hola", 2:"adios", 3:"hasta luego"}
dic2 = {4:"¿Cómo estás?", 5:"¿Te encuentras bien?"}

#Uso el método items y list para crearme una lista
tuple_dic1 = list(dic1.items())
tuple_dic2 = list(dic2.items())

#los uno como lista y devuelvo un diccionario unido
dic3 = dict(tuple_dic1 + tuple_dic2)
```

Por otro lado, los diccionario no pueden tener claves repetidas por lo que **en el caso de que haya claves repetidas ¿Cuál es la clave que se va a quedar Python?** y **¿Cómo funciona?**

Por ejemplo en estos dos casos que la clave `1` está repetida pero con distinto valor:

```
dic1 = {1:"hola", 2:"adios", 3:"hasta luego"}
dic2 = {4:"¿Cómo estás?", 5:"¿Te encuentras bien?", 1:"Buenos días"}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Python => 3.9

Si la versión de Python es 3.9 o más adelante, existe el operador `|` y el operador `|=` definidos como operadores **merge** y **update** respectivamente. Por lo que para unir los diccionarios ejecutaríamos el siguiente código:

```
dic1 = {1:"hola", 2:"adios", 3:"hasta luego"}
dic2 = {4:"¿Cómo estás?", 5:"¿Te encuentras bien?"}

#Creamos un nuevo diccionario unión de los otros dos
dic3 = dic1 | dic2
print(dic3)
```

**Salida:**

```
{1: 'hola',
 2: 'adios',
 3: 'hasta luego',
 4: '¿Cómo estás?',
 5: '¿Te encuentras bien?'}
```

Si queremos **actualizar un diccionario existente**, usamos el operador antes mencionado `|=`:

```
dic1 = {1:"hola", 2:"adios", 3:"hasta luego"}
dic2 = {4:"¿Cómo estás?", 5:"¿Te encuentras bien?"}

#Actualizamos el diccionario dic1
dic1 |= dic2
print(dic1)
```

**Salida:**

```
{1: 'hola',
 2: 'adios',
 3: 'hasta luego',
 4: '¿Cómo estás?',
 5: '¿Te encuentras bien?'}
```

Aunque la salida es la misma, en el primer output hemos tenido que crear un tercer diccionario y en el segundo, hemos actualizado `dic1`.

Esto se puede encontrar en la documentación de las nuevas versiones de Python de forma resumida [What’s New In Python 3.9](https://docs.python.org/es/3/whatsnew/3.9.html#dictionary-merge-update-operators). Y de forma más detallada en la documentación [PEP584](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0584/)

### Versiones anteriores a Python 3.9

Este método supone un gran avance en la facilidad de uso de Python, y sustituye métodos anteriores más *feos* o no tan facilmente entendibles por personas con poca experiencia en el lenguaje.

**Unión de diccionarios antes de Python 3.9**

```
dic1 = {1:"hola", 2:"adios", 3:"hasta luego"}
dic2 = {4:"¿Cómo estás?", 5:"¿Te encuentras bien?"}

#Aunque también era sencillo antes, la estrella no es conocida por todo el mundo,
#y no es lo primero que se le viene uno a la cabeza
{**dic1, **dic2}
```

**Actualización de diccionarios antes de Python 3.9**

```
dic1 = {1:"hola", 2:"adios", 3:"hasta luego"}
dic2 = {4:"¿Cómo estás?", 5:"¿Te encuentras bien?"}

dic1.update(dic2)
```

### ¿Qué sucede si usamos la misma clave?

De ambas formas siempre perdurara la última clave del diccionario. Es lógico que Python funcione así, ya que el segundo diccionario supondría una actualización sobre el primero, por lo tanto **en caso de clave repetida siempre permanece la del último diccionario.** Ejemplo:

```
dic1 = {1:"hola", 2:"adios", 3:"hasta luego"}
dic2 = {4:"¿Cómo estás?", 5:"¿Te encuentras bien?", 1:"repito la clave"}

dic1 = {1:"hola", 2:"adios", 3:"hasta luego"}
dic2 = {4:"¿Cómo estás?", 5:"¿Te encuentras bien?", 1:"repito la clave"}

#Como tenemos la clave 1 repetida, el segúndo diccionario
#significa que está actualizando su valor
print(dic1 | dic2)
dic1 |= dic2
print(dic1)
```

**Salida:**

```
{1: 'repito la clave', 2: 'adios', 3: 'hasta luego', 4: '¿Cómo estás?', 5: '¿Te encuentras bien?'}
```

Repito, **esto sucederá igual en Python 3.9, como en anteriores versiones**

Comment: Sería interesante indicar de qué diccionario se toma el campo si existe un índice repetido